# How can I verify certificate has "CA=true" basic constraint?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, x509

I'm new to openssl API

when I use the openssl APP with this command :

```
openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -text -noout
```

form it's output my interest is :

```
    ...
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE <-- this section I want to validate in my code
    ...
```

I want to validate the CA part using OpenSSL c API but can't figure how.
I've drilled down the APP src code but got lost when I've arrived to

```
openssl/crypto/ct/ct_prn:102

BIO_printf(out, "\n%*sExtensions: ", indent + 4, "");
if (sct->ext_len == 0)
    BIO_printf(out, "none");
else
    BIO_hex_string(out, indent + 16, 16, sct->ext, sct->ext_len);
```

**my question:** 
what is the proper way to iterate over the extensions , find tthe basic constrains section and **validate that my certificate is CA:TRUE**

**bonus question:** 
what is your method searching the openssl API for methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> bonus question: what is your method searching the openssl API for methods

Sadly, there's no easy method at times. I'll walk you through the steps I use to answer unique questions like this.

If you know what to look for, sometimes you can use a symbol browser like ctags. I don't use it however; instead, I usually grep the sources.

If you have ever heard OpenSSL is *"self documenting"*, this is the epitome of it.

---

> my question: what is the proper way to iterate over the extensions ,
>   find tthe basic constrains section and validate that my certificate is
>   CA:TRUE

After a while, you will get a feel for the interesting stuff. From the grep below, I know its the `NID_basic_constraints`.

```
openssl-1.1.0b$ grep -iR basic * | grep constraint
crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:    0x55,0x1D,0x13,                                /* [  505] OBJ_basic_constraints */
crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:    {"basicConstraints", "X509v3 Basic Constraints", NID_basic_constraints, 3, &so[505]},
crypto/objects/obj_dat.h:      87,    /* OBJ_basic_constraints            2 5 29 19 */
crypto/objects/obj_mac.num:basic_constraints        87
crypto/objects/objects.txt:!Cname basic-constraints
crypto/x509v3/v3_bcons.c:    NID_basic_constraints, 0,
crypto/x509v3/v3_purp.c:        NID_basic_constraints,  /* 87 */
crypto/x509v3/v3_purp.c:    /* Handle basic constraints */
crypto/x509v3/v3_purp.c:    if ((bs = X509_get_ext_d2i(x, NID_basic_constraints, NULL, NULL)))
...
```

From above, I know a few things. First, `v3_purp.c` is the file of interest. Second, `X509_get_ext_d2i(x, ...)` means `x` is a `X509*`. Third, `NID_basic_constraints` is the item of interest.

And here's the head of the function with the bits of interest. `BASIC_CONSTRAINTS` and both `bs->ca` look interesting.

```
static void x509v3_cache_extensions(X509 *x)
{
    BASIC_CONSTRAINTS *bs;
    PROXY_CERT_INFO_EXTENSION *pci;
    ASN1_BIT_STRING *usage;
    ASN1_BIT_STRING *ns;
    EXTENDED_KEY_USAGE *extusage;
    X509_EXTENSION *ex;

    int i;
    if (x->ex_flags & EXFLAG_SET)
        return;
    X509_digest(x, EVP_sha1(), x->sha1_hash, NULL);
    /* V1 should mean no extensions ... */
    if (!X509_get_version(x))
        x->ex_flags |= EXFLAG_V1;
    /* Handle basic constraints */
    if ((bs = X509_get_ext_d2i(x, NID_basic_constraints, NULL, NULL))) {
        if (bs->ca)
            x->ex_flags |= EXFLAG_CA;
        if (bs->pathlen) {
            if ((bs->pathlen->type == V_ASN1_NEG_INTEGER)
                || !bs->ca) {
                x->ex_flags |= EXFLAG_INVALID;
                x->ex_pathlen = 0;
            } else
                x->ex_pathlen = ASN1_INTEGER_get(bs->pathlen);
        } else
            x->ex_pathlen = -1;
        BASIC_CONSTRAINTS_free(bs);
        x->ex_flags |= EXFLAG_BCONS;
    }
    ...
}
```

Next, checkout `BASIC_CONSTRAINTS`. You want the `_st` because that's how OpenSSL names their structs.

```
$ grep -IR BASIC_CONSTRAINTS * | grep _st
include/openssl/x509v3.h:typedef struct BASIC_CONSTRAINTS_st {
```

And a quick peek at `BASIC_CONSTRAINTS_st`:

```
typedef struct BASIC_CONSTRAINTS_st {
    int ca;
    ASN1_INTEGER *pathlen;
} BASIC_CONSTRAINTS;
```

---

The final question may be, how do you get a hold of an `X509 *x`? Well, you get that from:

- `SSL_get_peer_certificate` (from an SSL connection)
- `PEM_read_X509` (convert from PEM encoding)
- `d2i_X509` (convert from ASN.1/DER encoding)
- etc...

***If*** you already have an `X509* x`, it looks like you only need to test for `x->ex_flags & EXFLAG_V1`.

Lather, rinse, repeat for `EXFLAG_V1` and `X509_st`:

```
$ grep -IR EXFLAG_V1 * | grep define
crypto/x509v3/v3_purp.c:#define V1_ROOT (EXFLAG_V1|EXFLAG_SS)
include/openssl/x509v3.h:# define EXFLAG_V1               0x40

$ grep -IR X509 * | grep _st | grep typedef
crypto/x509v3/pcy_int.h:typedef struct X509_POLICY_DATA_st X509_POLICY_DATA;
include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:typedef struct x509_st X509;
include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:typedef struct X509_algor_st X509_ALGOR;
include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:typedef struct X509_crl_st X509_CRL;
...
```

Comment: great explanation and +1 for the walk-through